# Error when trying to swipe to org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.interactions.HasTouchScreen

Tags: appium, appium-android

I am trying to swipe within the app and it is giving me the following error org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.interactions.HasTouchScreen

Please find my code details.
here is my main class

```html
public class Yf {

 WebDriver driver;
 // String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");

 WebDriverWait wait;

 DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
 Swipe swipe = new Swipe(driver);

 @BeforeTest
 public void initConfig() {

  cap.setCapability("deviceName", "R58M439LBRY");
  cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
  // cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Android");
  cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "9");
  cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.yellowfinbi.android");
  cap.setCapability("appActivity", "md5a479f257bdebd299ec30f02ebca2a5d0.LaunchActivity");

 }

 @Test
 public void Login() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
  RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
  WebElement SignInButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text,'Login')]"));
  SignInButton.click();
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  WebElement ServerURL = driver
    .findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[contains(@text,'Server URL (or address)')]"));
  ServerURL.sendKeys("https://chololo.yellowfin.bi/");
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  WebElement UserName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[contains(@text,'Username')]"));
  UserName.sendKeys("bobby.chodagam@yellowfin.bi");
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  WebElement PassWord = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[contains(@text,'Password')]"));
  PassWord.sendKeys("Sai79baba");
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  WebElement Login = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(@index,'8')]"));
  Login.click();
  Thread.sleep(15000);
  swipe.Scroll(driver, DIRECTION.LEFT, 1000);

 }

}
```

Please find the swipe method code below

```html
import org.openqa.selenium.Dimension;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.touch.TouchActions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.Augmenter;

public class Swipe {

 WebDriver driver;

 public Swipe(WebDriver driver) {
  this.driver = driver;
 }

 public enum DIRECTION {
  DOWN, UP, LEFT, RIGHT;
 }

 public void Scroll(WebDriver driver, DIRECTION direction, long duration) {
  Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
  TouchActions Action = new TouchActions(driver);

  int startX = 0;
  int endX = 0;
  int startY = 0;
  int endY = 0;

  switch (direction) {
  case RIGHT:
   startY = (int) (size.height / 2);
   startX = (int) (size.width * 0.90);
   endX = (int) (size.width * 0.05);
   Action.scroll(startX, startY).move(endX, startY).release().perform();
   break;

  case LEFT:
   startY = (int) (size.height / 2);
   startX = (int) (size.width * 0.05);
   endX = (int) (size.width * 0.90);
   Action.scroll(startX, startY).move(endX, startY).release().perform();
   break;

  case UP:
   endY = (int) (size.height * 0.70);
   startY = (int) (size.height * 0.30);
   startX = (size.width / 2);
   Action.scroll(startX, startY).move(endX, startY).release().perform();
   break;

  case DOWN:
   startY = (int) (size.height * 0.70);
   endY = (int) (size.height * 0.30);
   startX = (size.width / 2);
   Action.scroll(startX, startY).move(startX, endY).release().perform();
   break;

  }
 }

}
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Also here is the screen shot of the app that I am trying to swipe to the left. Thanks[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by declaring as follows

```
AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver; and initialising as 
driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
```

here is the final code

```html
mport org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.yellowfin.mobile.Swipe;
import com.yellowfin.mobile.Swipe.DIRECTION;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class Yf {

 AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;
 // String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");

 WebDriverWait wait;
 Swipe swipe;
 DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();

 @BeforeTest
 public void initConfig() throws MalformedURLException {

  cap.setCapability("deviceName", "R58M439LBRY");
  cap.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
  // cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Android");
  cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "9");
  cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.yellowfinbi.android");
  cap.setCapability("appActivity", "md5a479f257bdebd299ec30f02ebca2a5d0.LaunchActivity");
  driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
  swipe = new Swipe(driver);
 }

 @Test
 public void Login() throws InterruptedException {

  WebElement SignInButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(@text,'Login')]"));
  SignInButton.click();
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  WebElement ServerURL = driver
    .findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[contains(@text,'Server URL (or address)')]"));
  ServerURL.sendKeys("https://chololo.yellowfin.bi/");
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  WebElement UserName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[contains(@text,'Username')]"));
  UserName.sendKeys("bobby.chodagam@yellowfin.bi");
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  WebElement PassWord = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[contains(@text,'Password')]"));
  PassWord.sendKeys("Sai79baba");
  Thread.sleep(2000);
  WebElement Login = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(@index,'8')]"));
  Login.click();
  Thread.sleep(15000);
  swipe.Scroll(driver, DIRECTION.RIGHT, 10);
  swipe.Scroll(driver, DIRECTION.RIGHT, 10);
  swipe.Scroll(driver, DIRECTION.RIGHT, 10);
  swipe.Scroll(driver, DIRECTION.RIGHT, 10);
  
 }
}
```